# Change value of form input based on check box click

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form with validation, but im looking for a way to allow a check box to force a value for a form field so the validation will not see it as blank once the check box is clicked.

I currently have:

```
if (document.drop_list.Make.value == "")

    {

      message = message + "Make is missing\n";

      valid = false; 

    }
```

I also have a check box, with this function:

```
 // add event handler to checkbox
    element.addEventListener('change', function() {
 // inside here, this refers to the checkbox that just got changed
    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox_1');
    textbox.disabled = this.checked;
```

Can I add something to that function to force a value for:

```
<SELECT class="enteredMake" onchange=SelectModel(); name=Make id="textbox_2">
<OPTION selected value="">Vehicle Make</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

This way, it wont be blank, it would be, say "Checked"
allowing the validation to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So are you looking for something that will set the value of a `select` box once a checkbox has been ticked? For example:

```
selectbox = document.getElementById('myselectbox');
checkbox = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    selectbox.value = "1" 
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" />
<select id="myselectbox">
    <option value="-1">Please select...</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ww9W/)

Comment: This works when I change myselectbox to reflect a text input field. I see "1" appiear when I check the box. But when I try to use for a option select form element, it just goes blank, and the value is not set. Is there javascript to set the selected option value?

Comment: So [**this code**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ww9W/) doesn't work for you? Let me know, I might have misunderstood your question.